# Yarn JobHistory Error: Failed redirect for container_1400260444475_3309_01_000001

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

My MR job is executed successfully .But when i am checking its History getting error as:

```
Failed redirect for container_1400260444475_3309_01_000001

Failed while trying to construct the redirect url to the log server. Log Server url may not be     configured Unknown container. Container either has not started or has already completed or doesn't belong to this node at all.
```

Also my HistoryServer is running fine.
Good thing is,older jobs(retired ones) i can browse from JobHistory UI.
Only it is missing for recent jobs.

Do i need to change log rolling properties,retention period ?

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: I get this when clicking on "logs" link for the app logs.  And, same thing, it never makes it to the log history server UI either.  I'm wondering if it is because my job is so fast (a few seconds) that there is a polling interval from history server that is missed.  How long did yours take?

Comment: Please describe your environment.  If you were (2.1,2.4) non-inclusive, then you may be hitting https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/YARN-1206

Answer (score 6):

Try these steps

1. add to mapred-site.xml

> ```
> <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.address </name>
> <value>hostName:10020</value>
>
> <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.webapp.address</name>
> <value>hostName:19888</value>
> ```

2. add to yarn-site.xml

> ```
> <property>
>          <name>yarn.log.server.url</name>
>          <value>http://<LOG_SERVER_HOSTNAME>:19888/jobhistory/logs</value>
> </property>
> ```

3. start history server with
   $ mr-jobhistory-daemon.sh start historyserver

Comment: I'm using Hadoop 2.6.0-cdh5.7.1.
I put these settings (steps 1,2) on my nodes with resourcemanager and with nodemanager and restart nodes;
After that redirection begin to work.
Also I was confused because there is no setting 'yarn.log.server.url' in [yarn-default.xml] (https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.0/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/yarn-default.xml)

Comment: Running hadoop 2.7.6 and it worked perfectly doing exactly what you provided. Thanks!

Comment: Running cloudera-quickstart-vm-5.13.0, hadoop2.6.0-cdh5.13.0, its worked for me. After following step 1 and 2, in step 3 restarted the VM.....Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I got it fixed by adding actual hostname instead of 0.0.0.0 in mapred-site.xml

```
<name>mapreduce.jobhistory.address </name>
<value>hostName:10020</value>

<name>mapreduce.jobhistory.webapp.address</name>
<value>hostName:19888</value>
```

Answer (score 0):

And double check that map-reduce history server is running!

```
service hadoop-mapreduce-historyserver status
```

And accessible:

```
curl localhost:19888 -I
```